# Can we download android project code from google platform?

Tags: android

if the app is deployed to the google play

https://play.google.com/apps/publish

and if we have access to the developer console and to the link provided above can we download the application code from this platform or do we need to get the project files separately from the client.

I have got the project but I am confused whether I can download the project code from the google platform or should I ask the client

Comment: Q: What makes you think the project source code is going to be available on Google Play?  If that's what you're asking. Typically, the author does a "build", and uploads the binary .apk or a bundle to be published.  *NOT* the whole project, with all the source code!

Comment: Alright I got your answer.